# Bind / Unbind one PCIe device disables other

Tags: linux, drivers, pci-express

I have 2 SFPs, Both are plugged-in.
lspci shows they are at 0000:05:00.0 and 0000:05:00.1.
The device at 0000:05:00.0 is designated as "sfp2" and the device at 0000:05:00.1 is "sfp1".
"sfp1" is under DPDK control(bound to igb_uio driver) ad sfp2 is under kenel control (bound to ixgbe driver).

When ever I do a unbind of sfp1 from ugb_uio and bind to ixgbe, SFP2 could not receive any packets.
steps:

1. unbind sfp1

   ```
   echo 0000:05:00.1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.1/driver/unbind
   ```
2. bind sfp1 to ixgbe

   ```
   echo 0000:05:00.1 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ixgbe/bind
   ```
3. check RXCTRL register at 0x03000

   ```
   ethtool -d sfp2| grep 0x03000
   ```

   returns 0x00000.

my question is:

1. Am i doing the thing correctly? if so then why sfp2 is unable to
   accept any packet?
2. if i am wrong then what is the correct sequence?
3. where to look further to solve this problem?

NOTE: using dpdk-devbind.py to unbind and bind also this happens.

Thanks in Advance.